# How can I download the latest master branch in Git every time it is updated?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Some other devs and I are working on a project and we want to make sure we don't slip up and edit the same files at the same time another is editing, or that we edit something when someone has already edited. We are using Bitbucket if that matters. Is there a program, a built in function, or anything like that that will automate downloading the newest master branch? Or is it something we will have to write ourselves?

Comment: Maybe `git pull --rebase`? Or you could link that to cron and have it run every 5 minutes or something. Honestly though, that seems like a really bad idea.

Git is a revision control system, not a FTP server. Communicate with the other developers to ensure you don't start working on the same feature at the same time, develop on separate branches, and resolve your editing conflicts when they come up with a `git merge` or `git rebase`.

Comment: *we want to make sure we don't slip up and edit the same files at the same time another is editing* why not? the purpose of git is to be able to work on the same project with multiple developers at once